# VBA - How do I "ask" to excel search for cells with 0 in the content and higlight them if the cell above it's not empty?

Tags: vba, excel

I have already searched for this but I've had no success. My understanding of VBA is very poor.  So, it's difficult to search.

I intend to study and to learn more about this, but I need to know so much to solve this and complete a job.

Does anyone of you could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to change the range accordingly.

```
Sub Test()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:G100")
Range("A1").Select
    For Each cell In rng
    Cells.Find(What:=0, After:=ActiveCell, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Select
    If (ActiveCell.Row) <> 1 Then
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Value) Then
     ActiveCell.Select
     With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
         End With
     End If
     End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Slubee, thank you very much!
I had a problem with my spreedsheet, but as soon as possible I will test the code!
After this, I come back here to post a feedback.
Thank's again!

Comment: Something went wrong. The highlighted were the opposite that was my intention. That is, were highlighted the cells with 1 in the content.

I already tried to change the line "If (ActiveCell.Row) <> 1 Then" replacing for "If (ActiveCell.Row) <> 0 Then". This way I got I different result but not the one I'd like to.

Comment: If Activecell.row <> 0 is to make sure you are not in the 1st row. so you want to highlight if the above cell is empty?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Anyway, I want to highlight if the above cell is not empty.

Comment: But this was happening above the cells with the value 1 and I would like to happen above the cells with the value 0.

Comment: Sorry about my difficult to explain... I'm striving, but English it's not my native language and also I'm very beginner in VBA.

Comment: cells.find ..... line in the above code looks for 0.                                    Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Value) is checking if the above cell is not empty

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It looks right, but something it's still not working. I thought of something that had not yet mentioned, the 0 or 1 value in the cells are result from formulas. That change anything?

Comment: Try with :                                                                                       Cells.Find(What:=0, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Select